# Dual database possibilities (Firebase & Webhosting service)

Tags: mysql, database, firebase

Is it possible to use two databases, example, Firebase and an online webhosting server? I am developing an app that uses the webhosting server for the data and the firebase only for the chats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Firebase is very flexible when it comes to picking and choosing parts which you want to use.

You don't need to migrate away from whatever backend you already have if you just need to add in something that is unrelated to your site data, such as a support chat or something.

Instead, see it as an opportunity to discover Firebase by trying out something isolated like a chat using Firebase Database. You'll find your best fit by trying out the strengths and limits of the platform.

Comment: I am using 000webhost.com as my online server sir with my mobile application passing data via Volley method. All im only needing is the chat feature which is realtime from firebase sir and all I would just input in the firebase are just the usernames, passes and just names sir. Would it be fine sir? Perhaps by your opinion?

Comment: Absolutely. Firebase is "just a system" with and SDK and APIs like many other services. You decide what your app can and can not pass.

Comment: Thanks for this mind opening words sir! this got my idea running more colorful! Cheerio and God bless!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible but, you have to manage the back-end accordingly. I have created the app in which api is hosted in aws-EC2 and few part is in the Firebase. For example for some live changes I'm using the Firebase and for other things like getting feeds and all those thing i used aws EC2.

Comment: I have just now discovered AWS EC2 sir, I am currently using 000webhost.com as my webhosting server which I store my data and my only purpose of using firebase is for the username, pass and their names which is for the realtime chat. I'm working for my thesis by the way and we are prohibited of completely using firebase as our main storage for data as we are needed to apply what we are taught.

Comment: Sure you can use that kind of thing but u have to maintain things like foreign key kind of structure we use in database. Otherwise in future you will get some issues like data is available in your server and user is not available in your firebase or vice versa. Best of luck for your thesis.

Comment: I'm planning to separate them sir so they(2 databases) does not collide with each other's data. Thanks for opening my mind a little bit sir and also for the good luck! Cheerios and God Bless!